# Guess complete filename

Tags: autocomplete, rm

I have some files with really long names lying around on my server and writing the complete names is kind of a pita so I'm asking if my Linux system (Debian 7) can guess the complete filename?
I want to write something like

```
rm some_file_1
```

instead of

```
rm_some_file_1_very_long_information_bla_bla_foo_bar_meow
```

There is no other file than `some_file_1_very_long_information_bla_bla_foo_bar_meow` whose name contains `some_file_1`

Comment: There is also tab-completion.  Have you tried typing `some_file_1` followed by tab?

Comment: `TAB` works great, too. I think both (jw013's and Joseph R.'s) answers are good and simple ways to do it. I'll probably stick to the wildcard (`*`) method as my intent will be clearer. The `TAB` method is great because you will see the full filename (in case it was even found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [shell globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) are for (among other things):

```
echo some_file_1*
```

Note that I'm using `echo` instead of `rm` deliberately. When you are satisfied your glob has matched exactly the file(s) you wish to remove, you can then replace `echo` with `rm`.

Comment: That's exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is [autocompletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocompletion). Type the first few characters of the file name on the shell command line and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The file name is automatically completed if the prefix that you typed is unambiguous.

If there is an ambiguity, the shell will at least complete up to the point where there are multiple possibilities. For example, if there are files called `some_file_1`, `some_file_2` and `some_fiddlesticks`, and you type `some_` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then the characters `fi` are inserted (at least). Depending on your shell configuration, this may choose a file name to complete rather than merely inserting `fi`, and the behavior if you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly also varies.

Autocompletion is available out of the box in bash, zsh, (t)csh and fish as well as some BusyBox variants. On most ksh installations, you need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If your shell doesn't have completion, you can use wildcards: enter `rm some_file_1*` to delete all files whose name begins with `some_file_1`. Compared to the completion method, this has the disadvantage of being very unforgiving to typos. For example, if there's another file beginning with the same prefix, it will be deleted. If you accidentally put a space before the `*`, all files in the current directory will be deleted. You can put `echo` in front of the command to see what it'll do, then run the command again without `echo` to perform the operation. Alternatively, run `rm -i some_file_1*` to get prompted for every file name.